# Send form data to Mailchimp without redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, post

I am trying to send form data to MailChimp without redirecting to another page. Instead, I want a popup to display "Thank you for signing up!" How can this be achieved? I tried to use JQuery.post() to send the data, But I don't think it is working because of the Same Origin Policy for JQuery.post(). The .fail() would run and I cannot get any error messages from it. Please help.

[EDIT]: Added the code below

```
$("form.newsletter-signup-form").submit(function(event) {
    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();
    /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    var url = "http://empirecovers.us1.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post";
    /* Send the data using post */
    var posting = $.post(url);
    /* Put the results in a div */
    posting.done(function(data) {
        alert("done");
    });

    posting.fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("XMLHttpRequest: " + XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
        alert("textStatus: " + textStatus);
        alert("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
    });
    posting.always(function() { alert("finished"); });
});
```

[NOTE]: I also want to mention that I am using ASP.NET to implement this. I noticed that there's a MailChimp API for .NET to send data.

Comment: Are you trying to send cross domain POST via jQuery? Shouldn't you try using proxy?

Comment: There shouldn't be XSS restrictions. Post some code.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely post to your own ASP.NET page or handler or controller or whatever you're using, which will then generate the request to MailChimp either manually or through the API from your web server rather than from the client.

This gives you the control to do whatever you need to, including passing any secret keys or whatever the MailChimp API requires, and it gives you the control over exactly what you want your user experience to be, since you'll have the ability to post via AJAX to your own page.